# How to use $lookup more than once in against the same collection?

Tags: mongodb

I am migrating the db from mysql to mongo, so I need to create a view in mongo, for that purpose, I need to use the left outer joins, which is $lookup in mongo. But, I want to join something like

```
LEFT JOIN `contracts` `con` ON ((`c`.`company_id` = con`.`company_id`)))
LEFT JOIN `contracts` `con2` ON (((`c`.`company_id`=`con2`.`company_id`)
AND (`con`.`contract_id` < `con2`.`contract_id`))))
```

Is it possible to use `$lookup` twice against the same collection? I saw some queries which uses `$lookup` more than once in the aggregate function, but it uses against different collections.

Comment: Nothing stopping you doing that. The `collection` argument to `$lookup` will just accept any value which is a valid collection ( invalid would simply return no result ). I really suggest just trying it. If you have further problems, then please present a small sample of documents from each collection and the result you expect to achieve. It's quite possible that what you want to do can be done differently than what you know as the current SQL approach.

Comment: @NeilLunn, my issue is with this compariosn, AND (`con`.`contract_id` < `con2`.`contract_id`)